# Reading Access MDB file from ASP.NET 3.5 Web Service on 64 bit OS

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, .net-3.5, 64-bit

I run Windows Server 2008/IIS 7.

From a Web Service I attempt to read from a local mdb file.

If I set the target platform to any or x64 I get the error: The 'Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

If I set the target platform to x86 I get the error: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no 64-bit OLEDB provider for Jet. So no mdb access on 64-bit.
2. Assembly compiled for 32-bit on IIS running on a 64-bit OS requires that "Enable 32-Bit Applications" is set to TRUE in the Advanced Settings for the Application Pool of the Web Service.